# Return always the index.html with expressjs

Tags: routes, express

How can I return the `index.hmtl` page for every not defined route, expect the static files like CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have to add this line add the end of my `app.js`

```
app.use(function(req,res){
  res.render('index', {});
});
```